# DragDrop - DragEnter/DragLeave Events keep firing

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a drag/drop operation on a Canvas that is supposed to do something when an object gets dragged into and out of it. My problem is that the DragEnter/DragLeave events keeps firing as the mouse moves the object over it, not just on enter/exit. The faster the mouse is moving, the more frequently the events fire.

The Canvas DragOver Event moves the Canvas.Top/Left of the DraggedObject and I think that might be my problem, but I am not sure how I would fix this.

Comment: You are probably right, if you tell us _why_ you want to do that, maybe we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: I have a canvas with a bunch of Panels on it. The panels can be dragged around to rearrange them, or new ones can be added by dragging a new panel from a listbox onto the canvas. They can also be removed by dragging the panels out of the Canvas and back to the Listbox.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the sequence of events:

1. Your mouse moves from where you clicked it across the Panel.  No events fire.
2. Your mouse reaches the edge of the Panel and enters the Canvas.  The `DragEnter` event fires on the Canvas.
3. Your `DragEnter` handler moves the Panel so that it is now under the mouse.  Since the mouse is no longer over the Canvas (it is over the Panel), the `DragLeave` event fires.
4. Your mouse moves further, reaching the edge of the Panel again.  Steps 2 and 3 repeat.

The faster you move the mouse, the more events you will receive.

The essence of your problem is that drag-drop uses hit testing, and by moving your panel you are defeating the ability of hit testing to see "behind" your panel to know what container it is being dropped in.

The solution is to use your own code for drag and drop handling, which is really not difficult at all.  WPF's hit testing engine is powerful enough to do hit-testing behind the current object but drag-drop doesn't make use of this functionality.  You can use it directly however by using the `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` overload that takes a `HitTestFilterCallback` and a `HitTestResultCallback`.  Just pass it a filter that ignores any hits within the panel being dragged.

I've found that for scenarios like you describe, doing drag-drop by handling mouse events is actually easier than using the built in DoDragDrop because you don't have to deal with the complexity (DataObject, DragDropEffects, QueryContinueDrag, etc).  This additional complexity is very important for enabling scenarios of dragging between applications and processes, but does not help you for what you are doing.

Here's the simple solution:

1. On MouseDown with left button down, record the position (on MouseLeave erase the position)
2. On MouseMove with {left button down, position recorded, current mouse position differs by more than delta} set a flag saying drag operation is in progress & capture the mouse
3. On MouseMove with drag operation in progress, use hit testing to determine where your panel should be (ignoring the panel itself) and adjust its parenting and position accordingly.
4. On MouseUp with drag operation in progress, release the mouse capture and clear the "drag operation is in progress" flag

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! I converted my drag/drop properties to use MouseEvents instead of DragEvents and that got me the results I was looking for.

I had some originally had some concern doing so because I was dragging databound objects and custom classes, but they all came through just fine.

Comment: Great explanation. However I found a less intrusive solution (at least for my scenario) by setting myDraggedControl.IsHitTestVisible to false and resetting it to true after completion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit old, but I had the same issue. I was using an adorner to indicate where a dragged-thing was being dragged to. I would enable the adorner in `DragEnter`, then immediately register a `DragLeave` and disable the adorner, then a `DragEnter`...

`IsEnabled = false` didn't work for me, but `IsHitTestVisible = false` did. I put this in the constructor of my adorner, and now it all works beautifully:

```
public DragDropAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
{
    _layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement);
    _layer.IsEnabled = false;
    _layer.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: This simple fix actually worked for me and was suitable to my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I find it necessary to add a more accurate answer to what is happening, I will add that same answer in other questions related to this issue as well.

Ok, this is what happening:

1. You create a drag-drop operation.
2. While you drag-drop you want something visual to show along your mouse.
3. That visual element is being add to a grid or panel on Drag-Enter event and being remove on Drag-Leave event.
4. When it is being placed under the mouse you will get a drag-leave event as the element you drawing actually steals the drag-drop operation..

Solution: 
Make sure that `IsEnabled=false` for the element you draw under the mouse. 
That way it will not capture you drag-drop operation and you will not get flickering effect.

Comment: IsEnabled didn't work for me, had to do IsHitTestVisible as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the magic that fixed it was e.Handled = true;

I wanted to select a TabItem when something was dragged over it. This is my solution.

In a resource dictionary define:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="tabDragEnter" />
    <EventSetter Event="DragOver" Handler="tabDragOver" />
</Style>
```

Then the tabDragEnter handler:

```
private void tabDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {            
        TabItem m_TabItem = sender as TabItem;
        m_TabItem.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

and lastly the tabDragOver handler:

```
private void tabDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue recently, although it was in an Angular 6 framework, using reactive forms.  This is how I solved it for my situation:

Basically and briefly, I turned off change detection on that component while dragging was taking place.

1. import ChangeDetectorRef:

```
    import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

2. inject it into the constructor:

```
    constructor(private chngDetRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { //...
```

3. detach it on dragStart:

```
    private onDragStart(event, dragSource, dragIndex) {
        // ...
        this.chngDetRef.detach();
        // ...
```

4. reattach it on drop and dragEnd:

```
    private onDrop(event, dragSource, dragIndex) {
        // ...
        this.chngDetRef.reattach();
        // ...

    private onDragEnd(event, dragIndex) {
        // ...
        this.chngDetRef.reattach();
        // ...
```

If you have a lot of parent or layered components, you may have to do something about their change detection as well in order to see a substantial improvement.

Best of luck!