# wpf dragenter/dragleave problem

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am writing an WPF application, with drag and drop support within controls in the app, and also drag and drop between my desktop file and my app. I use adorner to change my mouse cursor.

The internal dragdrop operation between controls has no problem. The problem is dragdrop between desktop file and my app.

I set a DragEnter and DragLeave handler for my Window. When I drag a file into my app, DragEnter fired, but it's not just fired once, but keep firing with DragLeave alternatively on my application window.

What I already achieve is, I can manage to drag file into my app, with desired adorner; but if i keep holding the mouse and drag the file back to desktop, the adorner just stuck in the corner. I can't clear the adorner by using DragLeave, because the DragLeave event is firing non stop when I drag mouse in my app.

I want the DragLeave to fired only when the mouse cursor drag leave my application.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround that you could do for this scenario. 
[DragDrop - DragEnter/DragLeave Events keep firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632821/dragdrop-dragenter-dragleave-events-keep-firing)