# DragEnter & DragLeave: Avoid nasty flickering on custom drag preview

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mvvm-light

I've implemented a little WPF app to drag an animal from the shop in to my barn. ;-)

I'm using:

- MVVMlight and its `EventToCommand` behaviors
- The animal is a simple `Border` listening on `MouseDown`
- The barn is an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of the ViewModel. It listens to 3 events:

  - `DragEnter` (adds a dummy animal into the `ObservableCollection` to preview where the animal is placed in the barn)
  - `DragLeave` (removes the dummy animal if the animal isn't dropped)
  - `Drop` (sets the animal to the designated place in the barn).

Sorry. I don't have the reputation to upload images. So I try some ascii arts (try to image dragging the donkey into the barn):

```
Shop   | Barn
-------------------------
Mouse  | [Mouse] [Dog] 
Cat    | [.]
Dog    |  ^
Donkey-|--|
```

**Here's the problem:**

If I drag an animal into the barn onto it's designated space (the preview dummy):

1. `DragLeave` removes the dummy item and immediately the
2. `DragEnter` will be fired to redraw the dummy item. Goto step 1.

An inifite loop. The flickering is up and running!

**Does anyone know a nice little workaround?**

So here's the code of my ViewModel:

```cs
private string _dummy;
public ObservableCollection<string> Animals { get; private set; }

private void StartDrag(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var animal = element.DataContext as string;
    if (animal == null) return;
    System.Windows.DragDrop.DoDragDrop(element, animal, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void PreviewDrop(DragEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (string)))
        AddDummy();
}

private void StopDrop(DragEventArgs args)
{
    RemoveDummy();
}

private void Drop(DragEventArgs args)
{
    var animal = args.Data.GetData(typeof (string)) as string;
    if (animal == null) return;

    RemoveDummy();
    Animals.Add(animal);
}

private void RemoveDummy()
{
    if (_dummy == null) return;
    Animals.Remove(_dummy);
    _dummy = null;
}

private void AddDummy()
{
    if (_dummy != null) return;
    _dummy = ".";
    Animals.Add(_dummy);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Marcel

Comment: possible duplicate of [DragDrop - DragEnter/DragLeave Events keep firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632821/dragdrop-dragenter-dragleave-events-keep-firing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it. [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does the trick! Here are 2 solutions:

**First approach, the quick way:**
Just set all animals in the barn (by modifing the `ItemTemplate` in the target `ItemsControl`) to `IsHitTestVisible="False"`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
        <Border Background="Gray" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

So each item is still visible but no event is fired by the items nor the `ItemsControl`. But wait! What if I want to replace an animal by dragging a new one onto the old one??? I will need at least a proper `Drop` event?

**Second approach, the better way:**
I set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` **only** to the dummy animal (here I compare the string content against `"."` to check if it's a dummy).

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
        <Border Name="AnimalPlace" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" />
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value=".">
                <Setter TargetName="AnimalPlace" Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The last approach is suitable for the MVVM aspects and fits my needs perfectly. Not to mention that it can be adapted easily for more complex objects (more complex than a string to represent an animal).

I'am happy now :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I've just wasted hours trying to work around the DragLeave fired by my Canvas every time I mouse over my "drop point marker". Now I've set IsHitTestVisible to false on my marker control and there's no longer a DragLeave event to work around!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, you might just need to use flags to control the `DragLeave` and `DragEnter` code execution. Check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632821/dragdrop-dragenter-dragleave-events-keep-firing) to understand the sequence of events

Comment: I know the article. But the problem is: `DragLeave` is fired before `DragEnter`. Even if I would set flags inside `DragEnter` there aren't available in `DragLeave`. So I cannot distinguish if `DragLeave` is fired due to the mouse leaves the `ItemsControl` or enters one of its child items.