# HTML5 native DragEnter/DragLeave Events keep firing alternatively

Tags: angularjs, html, drag-and-drop

I am using native HTML drag'n'drop in my angular app and I found this event flickering problem

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632821/dragdrop-dragenter-dragleave-events-keep-firing) answer doesnt solve my issue, as they are moving the element manualy. I am leaving it on native implementation.

My simplified code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('amDnd', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      var el = $element[0];
      el.draggable = true;

      el.addEventListener('dragenter', function dragEnter(e) {
        console.log($scope.$id, 'dragEnter');
      }, false);
      el.addEventListener('dragleave', function dragEnter(e) {
        console.log($scope.$id, 'dragleave');
      }, false);

    }
  };
});
```

```css
div[am-dnd] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div am-dnd>
    <p>DRAG ME</p>
  </div>
  <div am-dnd>
    <h3>DRAG OVER THIS AREA</h3>
    <p>See the console, drag enter and leave are fired again and again while draging over
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quisquam, eaque, iure mollitia similique magnam voluptatem blanditiis distinctio nemo! Laboriosam porro iste maiores sequi magnam similique ad, in at. Omnis.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got a feeling that root of the "flickering" issue is that the `dragenter`/`dragleave` events are occurring for each child element of the second `am-dnd` directive.  There's a Stack Overflow question that discusses fixes for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements).

You might be able to declare a CSS rule like this:

```
.child-elements {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

... and apply this class to all child elements of the `am-dnd` directive using jqLite during the event trigger:

```
element.children().addClass("child-elements");
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhwL6cL2/) where the "flickering" events are minimized when the first directive is dragged over the second, but there's still some issues with the second directive being dragged over the first.  Nevertheless, I hope this points you in the right direction.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('amDnd', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('draggable', 'true');

            element.on('dragenter', function () {
                element.children().addClass("child-elements");
                console.log('dragEnter');
            });
            element.on('dragleave', function () {
                element.children().removeClass("child-elements");
                console.log('dragleave');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it pointed me to the problem, so I could solve it. Your solution is working and correct, but in my project I am using those directives nested so I came up with different solution which better fits my needs. Thank you again and have a nice day ;)

Comment: @Luckylooke Awesome - I'm glad to be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution which best fits my needs:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('amDnd', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      var el = $element[0],
        counter = 0;
      el.draggable = true;

      el.addEventListener('dragenter', function dragEnter(e) {
        if (e.target === el && !counter) {
          console.log($scope.$id, 'dragEnter');
        }
        counter++;
      }, false);
      el.addEventListener('dragleave', function dragLeave(e) {
        counter--;
        if (e.target === el && !counter) {
          console.log($scope.$id, 'dragleave');
        }
      }, false);

    }
  };
});
```

```css
div[am-dnd] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div am-dnd id='id1'>
    <p>DRAG ME</p>
  </div>
  <div am-dnd id='id2'>
    <h3>DRAG OVER THIS AREA</h3>
    <p>See the console, drag enter and leave are fired again and again while draging over
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quisquam, eaque, iure mollitia similique magnam voluptatem blanditiis distinctio nemo! Laboriosam porro iste maiores sequi magnam similique ad, in at. Omnis.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I had to edit my answer, because of copypaste mistake (counter--; was missing). Now it should be OK